# I have black mold spores in window air conditioning unit, why

Tags: hvac, mold

I have read on many sites how to get rid of black mold in a/c unit. What I would like to know, if I purchase a new unit, how would I make certain that this problem does not occur again. Why did this occur? I have noticed many family and friends a/c units have the same issue. Is this a problem with a/c units in general? i.e. No point in purchasing a new one as problem will likely occur again.

Comment: Keep the filter clean!  Dirty filters trap moisture and prevent the coils from drying.  It very important to clean regularly, do not let dirt build up.   Also eliminate any existing mold in the environment first.  Mold is living, it reproduces wherever there is moisture.

Comment: It sounds like a window unit, a major cause of mold is moisture if the unit is not slightly tilted to the back for drainage mold will always grow in the unit new or old. Most units require a 3-5 degree tilt to allow water to drain.